# Removing tab at end of a row in mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I have the following tab-separated input file. I want to remove the trailing tab at the end of the line and do that "in file" so that I don't have to output the modified data to a new file. The reason for this is that there is a lot of data so I don't want to be inefficient and read in data and then write it out again.

```
Hybridization REF   Gene_Symbol Chromosome  Genomic_Coordinate  TCGA-13-A5FT-01A-11D-A409-05    TCGA-13-A5FU-01A-11D-A409-05    TCGA-29-A5NZ-01A-11D-A409-05    TCGA-3P-A9WA-01A-11D-A409-05    TCGA-59-A5PD-01A-11D-A409-05    TCGA-5X-AA5U-01A-11D-A409-05    TCGA-OY-A56P-01A-12D-A409-05    TCGA-OY-A56Q-01A-11D-A409-05    TCGA-VG-A8LO-01A-11D-A409-05    TCGA-WR-A838-01A-12D-A409-05
cg00000029  RBL2    16  53468112    0.162232896986279   0.191627667901702   0.0712181967886229  0.0797617926225958  0.134907151266991   0.0541415985613948  0.0898579298345672  0.037865566345129   0.0681542463965581  0.101053013486289   
cg00000108  C3orf35 3   37459206    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
cg00000109  FNDC3B  3   171916037   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

To do this, I've been using variations of:

```
sed -i '' 's/\t\n/\n/g' input.txt
```

But this doesn't even remove the trailing tab. I'm using a Mac OS X so no GNU. What is the solution?

**EDIT**

I have posted the text file [here](http://www.pastebin.ca/3587703)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any answers that assume `\t` will be interpreted directly by sed are assuming GNU sed, which you don't have in OSX.  You do however have `bash`, so you have an easy printf conversion for your script:

```
$ sed -i '' -e $'s/\t$//' input.txt
```

The script in this case is being quoted with quotes that expand backslash escape sequences.  Note that this is a BASH feature, which we're using to put stuff more sensibly into sed.

Comparing this to the variant of the script in your question, I've put a dollar sign into the search regex to denote the end of the search string -- this script basically says:

- `s` - substitute
- /`\t$` - any tab that is at the end of the line,
- `//` - with an empty string.

We don't need the `g` ("global") option for the substitution, because sed will automatically apply the substitution to each line of your file.

Comment: I did it anyway but did I have to run the `dos2unix` command first?

Comment: @ghoti : Thanks for the comment with my answer. An eye opener indeed.

Comment: @user3313178 - glad this worked for you! Regarding dos2unix, there's nothing in the body of your question that would indicate that you need it, but you can `cat -vet file.txt | less` or `od -c file.txt | less` to get a better idea of the raw data you're dealing with. If you have DOS line endings, there are lots of strategies for removing them, and lots of questions here at SO that probably don't bear repetition here.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the end of line marker(`$`):

```
sed -i '' 's%\t*$%%g' input.txt
```

The `sed` expression replaces zero or more tabs (`\t*`) with empty string.

See `man sed`.

Comment: You're missing the suffix after `-i`. It's optional on Linux, but required on OS X.

Comment: The `-e` option isn't require if you only have one expression.

Comment: Similarly for this solution, the end of line tabs remain. Have you tried on the sample data above?

Comment: @user3313178, of course I have tested it. It's likely you have spaces in your file (not tabs), if you copied the sample data from the highlighted area. I had to click on `edit` button to copy original text.